# Selenium code example not working

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am following a code example in selenium and I keep getting the error "Error: Could not find or load main class Test." I am not sure what is causing this as I downloaded and unzipped selenium and extracted the jar files in Eclipse. I also have the class "Test" under the appropriate file and I am not sure what is causing this problem. Here is the code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling 'Test'?

Comment: What do mean? I just hit run in eclipse

Comment: I suspect your problem has nothing to do with Selenium, but with Java and Eclipse. Google Java+Eclipse+tutorial!

Comment: @SpockRock The error you gave was "Error: Could not find or load main class Test.", which is not shown in the above code snippet. Hence, I asked where you were calling it.

Comment: can you provide us with the Test class ?

Comment: Ok sorry I renamed "test" to "Example"and the error message is actually "Error: Could not find or load main class Example"

Comment: I also looked up a lot of installation tutorials so I believe I have everything configured right. Also, this code is directly from  seleniums website so I'm not sure what I did wrong

Comment: @SpockRock OpenQa has seen its final days as this link says:
http://www.openqa.org/

Comment: So this is a deprecated program?

Comment: yes, I suppose it is.

Answer (score 0):

Update your run configuration in Eclipse. It should point to Example class.